# Seek bar changing text size

Tags: android, user-interface, seekbar

I want to change the text size of an edit text using seek bar and every time I close the activity and reopen it the seek bar automatically increase the text size, this is the code:

```
package com.e_orthodoxy.orthodox_prayers;
    
public class WakeupActivity extends Activity {

    private SharedPreferences prefs;
    private SeekBar seekbar;
    private EditText edittext;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wakeup);
        
        seekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
        edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.id_wakeup_txt);
        
        prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        
        float fs = prefs.getFloat("fontsize", 12);
        seekbar.setProgress((int)fs);
        edittext.setTextSize(seekbar.getProgress());
        

        seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar){
                prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor ed = prefs.edit();
                ed.putFloat("fontsize", edittext.getTextSize());
                ed.commit();    
            }
            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar){
                
            }
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser){
                edittext.setTextSize(progress);
            }
        });
        
        
    }
    
    
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        
        Intent intent_wakeup_back = new Intent (WakeupActivity.this, DailyPrayersActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent_wakeup_back);
        finish();
    }   
}
```

Comment: so you want the seek bar to start from 12 (default value) every time you reopen your activity? in this case don't commit the new font size in onStopTrackingTouch because this will save the last value of the font size in your app's cache

Comment: no i want the seek bar to start from the size the user save

Comment: please read the following from android developers: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextSize%28float%29, the text size is calculated base as scaled pixel, to solve this issue use pixels to set the size of the text (TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX) your code will be :  edittext.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,seekbar.getProgress()); I'll add this as an answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

replace setTextSize(float size) with setTextSize(int unit,float size)
and use TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX for the unit

```
float fs = prefs.getFloat("fontsize", 12);
seekbar.setProgress((int)fs);
//edittext.setTextSize(seekbar.getProgress());
edittext.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,seekbar.getProgress());
```

and don't forget **onProgressChanged**:

```
 //edittext.setTextSize(progress);
 edittext.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,progress);
```

Answer (score -2):

All the code write in your `onCreate()` methodm and follow the typecasting (TextView and SeekBar):

```
SeekBar seekBar =(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
        SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
```

```
float fs = prefs.getFloat("fontsize", 12);
seekBar.setProgress((int)fs);
textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,seekBar.getProgress());

seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
        textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,seekBar.getProgress());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = prefs.edit();
        ed.putFloat("fontsize", textView.getTextSize());
        ed.commit();
    }
});
```