# How to change text size using seekbar in listview in android, i used textview from another layout for the listview item

Tags: android, listview, seekbar, settext

I'm working on a bible app and im using listview, i have a seekbar for the users, if they want to adjust the fontsize..they can use the seekbar

this is my code:

seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

```
        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.item_version);

        @Override

        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar){
            setContentView(queso);
            prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor ed = prefs.edit();
            ed.putFloat("fontsize", text.getTextSize());
            ed.commit();
            // setContentView(R.layout.activity_samples);

        }
        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar){

        }
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                                      boolean fromUser){

            text.setTextSize(progress);

        }
    });
```

>
 public void viewAll1(){

```
        Cursor cursor = myDB.getAllData2();

        String[] from = new String[]{DBAdapter.KEY_NAME};
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.item_version};

        SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter =
                new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item_layout, cursor, from, to, 0);




    ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    myList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);



}
```

Comment: its very easy. however if you add the xml code for the TextView to have a look, that will be great

Comment: thank you for your response :) i am new to android and i am new here. i tried this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18452037/seek-bar-changing-text-size , however when i use the seekbar, the activity stops

Comment: From what I read you are trying to update the text size of a listview. Looking at your code it looks like you are updating the text size of the textview found in the row layout which is likely the issue. You'd need to update all of the textview's in the listview. If you provide additional code we can probably help out a little more.

Comment: i did it by adding TextView text= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.item_version); inside onProgressChanged, now my problem is, items in listview is not changing fontsize simultaneously :( please help